# Cordova.framework is missing in my project

Tags: cordova, xcode4.5

I am working for a project already build with previous version of phonegap. I don't know if that version included the Cordova setup (>1.3) or not.

The problem, is that when i cloned the project and tried to build it in Xcode, I got the `Cordova.framework` in red.
[image]

Please I need you to point me what I need to do to get in the right path since this project is not developed by me and also this is my first experience with phonegap (but not iOS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that changed in PhoneGap 2.0. There is no longer a pre-built Cordova.framework. The Cordova source is now copied into the project as part of project creation.

http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/improvements-in-cordova-2-0-0-for-ios/

There's probably some information in one of the Readme files, or on the phonegap website, about how to convert from an earlier version.

And, here it is (under upgrading from 1.9 to 2.0): 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_upgrading_ios_index.md.html

Basically, after installing 2.x, create a new project and copy some of the contents of the new project into the old project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you've got "CordovaLib" directory when you go to your project by finder? if so, there is "VERSION" file which will tell you what version you have.